# Opposite parametrization of closed plane curve

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

This may be trivial but I cannot fully wrap my head around it:

Suppose we have a simple closed regular differentiable plane curve $\alpha : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ parametrized in arc length. Moreover suppose that is it positively oriented (the normal vector always point to the interior of the curve) then define $\beta(s):=\alpha(-s)$ show that it is negatively oriented (and v.v. of course). My issue is that while taking derivatives I get lost in changing signs, thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** If you define the normal as the derivative of $\frac{\alpha'(s)}{\|\alpha'(s)\|}$, as you suggest in your question, then the statement is not correct. The fact that the normal vector points inwards doesn't tell anything about how you walk through the curve (counterclockwise or clockwise).

Example:
$$ \begin{align*}
\alpha_1(s) &= \left( \cos (s),\sin(s)\right) \\
\alpha_2(s) &= \left( \cos (-s),\sin(-s)\right) 
\end{align*}
$$

Taking the second derivatives gives the normal vectors. In both cases, the normal vectors point inwards. However, $\alpha_1$ parametrises the circle counterclockwise; $\alpha_2$ clockwise.

**(2)** However, for plane curves one often defines the normal as $N=JT$, where $J$ stands for "rotating the vector 90 degrees counterclockwise". In this case, the statement is true (just use the right hand rule).

Comment: Thank you! This one example came to my mind and is the one that made me ask this question here. What do you think is the misunderstanding ? Can my question be made correct?

Comment: Well, the misunderstanding is that your "definition" of positive orientation isn't right. We found a counterexample, so the question cannot be made correct.

Comment: The point of the exercise is to show that "any curve can be positively oriented" so if we have a negatively oriented curve we can just put the minus in the argument and we're done.

Comment: I see. As your question is written now, I interpreted that you regarded "positive orientation" as defined by "normal vectors pointing inwards". But nevertheless, indeed, you just need to change $s$ into $-s$.

Comment: Yes this is my definition, so is this correct? How do I show that?

Comment: I think I know what the confusion is all about! Let me add it in the answer.